# read path name with spaces then use the variable into find command

Tags: shell, scripting, path, variable

I need to ask the user to provide a path name (which will here have a space) to launch a find command:

```
read -r -e -p "Folder:" folder
Folder :/mnt/My\ folderX/
echo $folder
```

gives:

```
My\ folderX/
```

But..

```
find $folder | sort -rn
```

gives:

```
find: /mnt/My\: No such file or directory
find: folderX/: No such file or directory
```

and

```
find "$folder" | sort -rn
```

gives:

```
find: /mnt/My\ folderX/: No such file or directory
```

Is there something I did wrong? Can't figure out why the second command won't run as it should take it as:

```
find /mnt/My\ folderX/ | sort -rn
```

Which works perfectly.

Many thanks

Comment: which shell are you using ?

Comment: i'm using sh (on mac os x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `-r` `read` will prevent the `\` from being an escape character, so either don't type the `\` or don't use `-r`.

So try it as follows:

```
read -rep "Folder: " folder
find "$folder" | sort -rn
```

and enter `/mnt/My folderX` without any escapes

or

```
read -ep "Folder: " folder
find "$folder" | sort -rn
```

and enter `/mnt/My\ folderX` (or `/mnt/My folderX` without the escape--you'll read the whole line into `folder` so you don't need to escape it either way)